# Create a HotSpot which requires a username and password

Tags: wireless, server, hot-spot

I wish to set up a wireless access point which requires a username and password in order for clients to use the internet. 
The network setup will be internet modem connected to an Ubuntu Server (2 networks cards). The first network cards to get the internet to the server and the second network card to connect the the wifi hotspot. The server will host the software such as ([Example software for windows](http://www.antamedia.com/hotspot/)) which will control the user connected by forcing them to login with the credentials given at the reception. Can some suggest some software that I can use?

Not sure if [PacketFence](http://www.packetfence.org/home.html) is what I need? If yes do I needs some special hardware?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone has some suggestions or hardware software I can start to experiment?